# 6D (2,0) superconformal field theory

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, field-theory, superconformality

I'm looking for a good reference book or textbook to study on 6D (2,0) superconformal field theory as a part of string theory.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly encourage you to read [Superconformal Field Theories in Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0608014) and [Six-Dimensional Superconformal Field Theories and Their Torus Compactifications](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Ehamanaka/ohmori_k16.pdf), the first one is an excellent introductory text and the second one discuss some compactification of the six dimensional theories.

It is also always important to have the classical [Comments on String Dynamics in Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603003) and the *"status of the art"* review of the topic [Top Down Approach to 6D SCFTs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.06467) in mind, this last reference can guide you perfectly through literature.

Talks on relevant modern developments in $6d$ SCFTs:

1. [Cumrun Vafa - On 6d Supersymmetric Conformal Field Theories](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHgBoEKrCp)
2. [Jonathan Heckman, 6D SCFTs from F-theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ9QYM66g0I)
3. [Jonathan Heckman - Top down approaches to 6d SCFTs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y33PvVSTpak)
4. [Jonathan Heckman: Effective Field Theories From String Compactification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sERFLnONC3A)

Answer (score -3):

Six D super conformal is correct hence why history has tried to show us it applies to giza the zodiac the yugas the vesica piscis gizas meas is 360 x 540 18 cubits cut off each side and top and bottom the calendar goes 30,30,31,30,30,31,30,30 31,30,30,31 and that's 364 with one day of rest the sabbath jubilee day of rest . The world is just three algorithms 123456789 159483726,186429753 each universe is six algorithms 3 and 3 two heavs two hells two earth's